# Using CSokcet and CWinThread, PostMessage from thread does not work

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, network-programming

I'm learning `network programming` on `MFC` and have referenced Flounder's guide here: http://www.flounder.com/kb192570.htm to mess with multi-thread and socket. But my work is simpler.


What I am trying to do is make a multi-thread server client model. The server just sitting around and listening, while the clients do telnet to it. Once there are connections, the server will make threads to handle connection in `OnAccept()`. On the creation, the thread will `PostMessage` with its thread ID to the main GUI. The GUI then handle that message with a function to pop out a `MessageBox` to display the thread ID. Just simple like that.


**My problem is:** in spite of the threads successfully made, and so on the socket handle(I have checked it on `netstat`) the inform message from thread have never been sent to GUI.


Here is my code:

`CListenSocket.h` and `CConnectSocket.h` are pretty the same in .h (derived from `CSocket`)

```
......
public:   
//Handle CWnd pointer from main GUI
   void SetParrent(CWnd * w) { windowsParrent = w; }
   CWnd * GetParrent() { return windowsParrent; }
protected:
   CWnd *windowsParrent;
.......
};
```

`CClientThread.h` (derived from `CWinThread`)

```
....
public:
   void SetParrent(CWnd * w) { windowsParrent = w; }
   CWnd * GetParrent() { return windowsParrent; }

   SOCKET handleThreadSocket;
   CConnectedSocket threadSocket;
protected:
   CWnd *windowsParrent;
....
```

Now when I make the listen socket, I have passed the GUI's CWnd pointer to it:

```
CListenSocket m_Listener;
....
m_Listener.SetParrent(this);
m_Listener.Create(1001);    
m_Listener.Listen();
```

Then `OnAccept()` of `CListenSocket` the thread is made, yet I did not forget to pass the CWnd pointer...

```
void CListenSocket::OnAccept(int nErrorCode)
{
   if(nErrorCode != 0)
   {
       CSocket temp_soc;
       CClientThread *pThr = (CClientThread*)AfxBeginThread(
                                            RUNTIME_CLASS(CClientThread),
                                            THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
                                            0,
                                            CREATE_SUSPENDED);

       pThr->SetParrent(windowsParrent);           
       pThr->handleThreadSocket = temp_soc.Detach();
       pThr->ResumeThread();
   }    
   CSocket::OnAccept(nErrorCode);
}
```

`CThreadClient.cpp` : thread creation

```
BOOL CClientThread::InitInstance()
{
   threadSocket.Attach(handleThreadSocket); 
   if (threadSocket == NULL)
   {
    return FALSE;
   }    
   if (windowsParrent == NULL)
   {
       return FALSE;
   }
   windowsParrent->PostMessage(THREAD_STARTED,0,(LPARAM)m_nThreadID);
   return TRUE;
}
```

Finally, I mapped the `THREAD_STARTED` with a function just to do this simple thing:

```
LRESULT CServerSideDlg::OnThreadStart( WPARAM, LPARAM lparam )
{
   UpdateData(TRUE);
   DWORD ThreadID = (DWORD)lparam;
   CString echo;
   echo.Format("%d",ThreadID);     
   UpdateData(FALSE);
   AfxMessageBox("Thread stated: "+echo);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the mapping:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CServerSideDlg, CDialog)
...
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
ON_MESSAGE (THREAD_STARTED, OnThreadStart)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Thread works, connection socket also works, but there is no message have been posted. Please help, where were I wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you add `ON_MESSAGE(THREAD_STARTED, OnThreadStart)` to your CServerSideDlg BEGIN/END message map?

Comment: Yes, I did. and `THREAD_STARTED` was defined as `WM_USER+200`

Comment: Are you sure this line `if (threadSocket != NULL)`is correct? After attach I would assume it will return non NULL.

Comment: That's true, it is my mistake. But strange thing is both ==NUL or !=NULL the result will the same !? I have make 2 cmd and telnet both of them to the server. Then check `netstat -an` and find both `ESTABLISHED` there, so we can assume the thread works, right? I have no idea now....

Comment: `WM_USER+x` is the wrong range. This range is reserved for use by the implementer of a window class. If you need application private messages for communication, use `WM_APP+x` instead.

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not the case. I have changed like your suggestion, but there is no message come out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work around for this, but I still don't known why my previous work didn't works as I expected.


I changed `CListenSocket.h` to this:

```
public:
void SetParentDlg(CDialog *pDlg) {parrentDlg = pDlg;}
....
protected:
CDialog *parrentDlg;
```

So what I am trying to do is not storing `CWnd` in socket, but `CDialog` from the GUI. Now when I create socket:

```
m_Listener.Create(1001);    
m_Listener.Listen();
m_Listener.SetParentDlg(this);
```

By doing this, I can override the socket's `OnAccept()` to a function at the main GUI:

```
void CListenSocket::OnAccept(int nErrorCode)
{
if(nErrorCode == 0)
{
    ((CServerSideDlg*)parrentDlg)->OnAccept(); //Here I use the function OnAccept() from GUI to handle accepted connections.
}   
CSocket::OnAccept(nErrorCode);
}
```

Then on my Dlg, I just make a public method `OnAccept()` to create thread and pass `CWnd` to the thread.

```
void CServerSideDlg::OnAccept()
{

   CSocket temp_soc;
   if (m_Listener.Accept(temp_soc))
   {
    CClientThread *pThr = (CClientThread*)AfxBeginThread(
                                        RUNTIME_CLASS(CClientThread),
                                        THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
                                        0,
                                        CREATE_SUSPENDED);

   pThr->SetParrent(this);         //pass CWnd to thread  
   pThr->handleThreadSocket = temp_soc.Detach();
   pThr->ResumeThread();
   }
}
```

The rest is unchanged, and it works.


So, why I cannot pass `CWnd` from GUI to socket and then to thread? I can only pass it ONE time from GUI to thread... Any idea, please?